# Set minDate in jQuery datepicker to specific day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker and want to be able to basically say "if it is a certain day, make minDate a specific weekday"

So i'm getting the day using this:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dayToday = dateToday.getDay();
```

and then i'm checking if todays date meets a certain condition:

```
if (dayToday =< 3) { // if today is Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday
  setMinDate = 5; // I want to set the minDate to be Friday (5)
}
```

Then I want to pass this to the date picker:

```
$("#date").datepicker( {
  minDate: setMinDate, // Pass the number to the minDate
  maxDate: "+2M",
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

The problem is, in the `minDate`, 5 means "5 days from today" and not Friday. Does anyone know how I can make this relate to a day of the week, not days from todays date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the difference by yourself and pass the "offset" as that is the expected value:

```
if (dayToday =< 3) { // if today is Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday
  setMinDate = 4 - dayToday  ; // calculate the days to add
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please code it like this:

```
if (dayToday =< 3) { // if today is Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday
   setMinDate = -4  ; // calculate the days to add
}
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy", 
    minDate: setMinDate, 
    maxDate: "+1M +1D" 
});
```

Comment: This would just give me tomorrow's date from what ever day it is today - this isn't what I want.